# Agregar texto ingresado en una tabla html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo 
home.html

```
Nombre: <input type="text" id="nombre">
<button type="button" id="add">Agregar</button>

<table id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="espacioNomb">

      </td>
      <td class="espacioNomb">

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Lo que desea hacer es que al ingresar un nombre en input, me lo insterte en la `<td class="espacioNomb">`

esto es lo que estaba haciendo pero no llega la informacion a la tabla de testing.html

```
$("#add").on("click", function(){
  $('#test > tbody').append('<tr><td>'+$("#nombre").val());
});
```

Comment: He metido ese código en un jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/cjed80pk/) y yo lo veo funcionando correctamente, cual es el problema que te estás encontrando?

Comment: @frikinside su problema es que tiene el HTML en dos paginas distintas...

Comment: @lois6b Posiblemente tengas razón y que yo haya supuesto de más que los dos htmls se cargan en la misma página maestra. A ver si nos puede resolver la duda, pero seguramente que tengas razón.

Comment: @frikinside supuse que no se cargan en la misma pagina porque si no le  funcionaría

Comment: No están en la misma pagina son paginas distintas pero en el mismo proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

El problema yace que **home.html** es una pagina, y **testing.html** es otra página.

Por tanto con el script se esta ejecutando solo en **testing.html** y por tanto no encuentra ciertas variables que yacen en la página **home.html**.

Lo que bien puedes hacer es hacer un envío desde **home.html** por medio de javascript hacia **testing.html**, y este al cargar, recupere esos datos y los almacene en las respectivas casillas que se necesite.

O bien cada vez que guardes en la pagina **home.html** lo almacenes en una variable y una vez que estés listo con esto, lo hagas envío por `ajax` o por un `window.location` pasándole como parámetro esa variable que puede ser un `JSON`

Espero que esto te vaya orientando de mejor manera. Éxito en tu proyecto!

Comment: otra opcion para que funcione hacer un include en php, pero dependera el lenguaje de programacion

Comment: Pero php trabaja por el lado del servidor y no del cliente. Y por lo que veo su pregunta es de parte de cliente simplemente :D

Comment: por eso el comentario!,gracias

Comment: Ya solucione el problema, ahora como hace para que se me inserte en un `td` especifica, digamos que tenga `<td class="espacioNom"></td>` cuando ingrese el valor que se me inserte en esa td

Comment: depende como hayas solucionado lo anterior. Al hacer el insertado en la tabla puedes hacerlo de dos modos. Uno es hacer append, o el otro es hacer `$("#test").html('<tr><td class="espacioNom"></td></tr>');` Esencialmente lo que hace esto es que se escriba código html dentro de la etiqueta test que ya sabemos que es una tabla.

Comment: yo el `td` lo ya esta creado, lo que necesito es ponerle ese valor a ese td especifico y que no me cree otro `td`

Comment: puedes ocupar posteriormente el `addCalss()` al `td` que estas ocupando. Por ello es que al menos yo lo agrego con `.html()`